# Reverse two finger scroll direction with BCM5974?

Tags: xorg, mouse, xinput

I'm looking to reverse the scroll direction specifically on my Apple trackpad, and I'm not sure if there's an input option to do so:

```
Device 'bcm5974':
Device Enabled (144):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (146): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (262): 1
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (263):   2.500000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (264):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (265):    12.500000
Synaptics Edges (266):  108, 1172, 68, 732
Synaptics Finger (267): 25, 30, 256
Synaptics Tap Time (268):   180
Synaptics Tap Move (269):   66
Synaptics Tap Durations (270):  180, 180, 100
Synaptics Tap FastTap (271):    0
Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (272):  75
Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (273):    282
Synaptics Two-Finger Width (274):   7
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (275): 30, 30
Synaptics Edge Scrolling (276): 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (277):   1, 1
Synaptics Move Speed (278): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.132538, 40.000000
Synaptics Edge Motion Pressure (279):   30, 160
Synaptics Edge Motion Speed (280):  1, 120
Synaptics Edge Motion Always (281): 0
Synaptics Off (282):    0
Synaptics Locked Drags (283):   0
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (284):   5000
Synaptics Tap Action (285): 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Click Action (286):   1, 3, 2
Synaptics Circular Scrolling (287): 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (288):    0.100000
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (289): 0
Synaptics Circular Pad (290):   0
Synaptics Palm Detection (291): 0
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (292):    10, 200
Synaptics Coasting Speed (293): 20.000000, 50.000000
Synaptics Pressure Motion (294):    30, 160
Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (295): 1.000000, 1.000000
Synaptics Resolution Detect (296):  1
Synaptics Grab Event Device (297):  1
Synaptics Gestures (298):   1
Synaptics Capabilities (299):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
Synaptics Pad Resolution (300): 1, 1
Synaptics Area (301):   0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Noise Cancellation (302): 5, 3
```

Is there any way I could swap the axes for two finger scrolling to make it more natural? If I globally swap it, then my mouse scrolls backwards too :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap buttons 4 (up), 5 (down), 6 (left), and 7 (right) on the button map for the device appropriately.

Comment: I suppose that would do it :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also reverse scrolling distance from 30 30 to -30 -30, with the added bonus that this does not reverse the mouse wheel behavior, only the touchpad.