# Can I Xmodmap only a specific device?

Tags: xmodmap, xinput

I'd like to reverse scroll direction, but only on my BCM5794 multitouch trackpad. Is this possible?

Comment: [Didn't we cover this one already?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33114/reverse-two-finger-scroll-direction-with-bcm5974)

Comment: That switches it for both my external USB mouse as well as the trackpad. How can I do it for _only_ the touchpad?

Comment: Weird. Sounds like a xinput problem then.

Comment: Is there something I can do in `.Xmodmap` to limit it to only BCM5974?

Comment: No. `xmodmap` affects the virtual core pointer device.

Comment: Is there any other way I can configure only this input?

Comment: `setxkbmap` has a `--device` argument, combining this with the right `id` from `xinput --list` might help here (if `setxkbmap` can be used to specify what you asked for).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes:

```
xinput set-button-map ID <button map>
```

Where you find the **`ID`** via `xinput list` and the `<button map>` is what you would have passed to `xmodmap`.  For instance I replace buttons on my USB mouse but I don't want my trackpad munged, my `~/.Xmodmap` used to look like this:

```
pointer = 1 17 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 2 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

But using that changes all pointing devices including my built in trackpad, so I know that the `xinput` id is 10 so I run this:

```
xinput set-button-map 10 1 17 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 2 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```