# Can I xmodmap only a specific keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap

I'd like to swap some keys but only in external keyboard. Is this possible with xmodmap?

I've found this question:
[Can I Xmodmap only a specific device?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38195/can-i-xmodmap-only-a-specific-device)
but it refers only to mouse.

---

I found here http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Configuring_keyboards

that "The Xmodmap/Setxkbmap Method ... changes how X handles the keycodes it receives" so one could think that it's not possible, but I can call:

```
setxkbmap -device <device_id>  -variant dvorak
```

and I obtain (partially) my desired result. So I have dvorak layout on external and "basic"=qwerty on my laptop keyboard.
And I'd like to have my custom layout on external keyboard.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no. I went through this a while ago, and I ended up using xorg rules. In short, create a new keymap using `xkb`, not `xmodmap` (I suspect the latter is deprecated anyway), then create a new rule in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`, with `MatchProduct "FOO"`.

Comment: Thanks Sparhawk, please look at edit. If I won't succeed I'll try your way.

Comment: Oh okay, good find! I probably went the "newer" way because I was also running [at-home-modifier](https://gitlab.com/at-home-modifier/at-home-modifier-evdev/wikis/home) on a specific keyboard, but your way looks like it should work.